# Change the max and min date in CultureInfo

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Is it possible to change the max and min date for a DateTimePicker using CultureInfo("ar-SA") or any Culture in general?

This the sample code that changes the Culture:

```
Dim CultureInfo As CultureInfo
CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("ar-SA")
CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = New System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo
Application.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo
```

If a new window containing a DateTimePicker (DTP) is then opened, that DTP has:

> .MinDate = 1900-04-30
> .MaxDate = 2077-11-16

Without setting the CultureInfo, the values for the DTP are

> .MinDate = 1753-01-01
> .MaxDate = 9998-12-31

Trying to set the `DTP.MinDate` to `New DateTime(1800, 1, 1)` gives an error of:

> DateTimePicker does not support dates before 04/30/1900 12:00:00 ص.

and trying to set the `DTP.MaxDate` to `New DateTime(2100, 1, 1)` gives an error of:

> DateTimePicker does not support dates after 12/31/9998 12:00:00 ص.

Also, note the discrepancy in the year in the latter case.

[image]

Comment: The date is limited between 30/4/1900 and 13/5/2029 so any advice about how to deal with this limited range

Comment: The min and max date for what? A calendar control? What sort of application is this, and what exact control? (I wouldn't expect the min/max to be configured in the culture, but in the control.)

Comment: And you can write it shorter: `Dim CultureInfo As New CultureInfo("ar-SA")`

Comment: If you check the value of `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.MinSupportedDateTime` you will find it is 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000, which is not the year 1900. Also, using a class name ("CultureInfo") for a variable name can create confusion.

Comment: if you display another window after execute these lines  the DateTimePicker.MinDate  and DateTimePicker.MaxDate  will change @Andrew Morton

Comment: Try to create a window with one button, the purpose for this button is to change the culture to (ar -sa) and then move you to another window that have a datetimepicker you will notice the min and max date is change.

Comment: @abdulrahmanb I edited that information into the question for you. I noticed that the MaxDate was 2077-11-16 - are you using Windows 10, or an earlier version?

Comment: @abdulrahmanb [Windows Hijri Calendar](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23226/Windows-Hijri-Calendar) might be useful to you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.umalquracalendar.minsupporteddatetime?view=net-5.0

Comment: @abdulrahmanb The link from Hans Passant leads to "The UmAlQuraCalendar class supports only dates from 04/30/1900 00.00.00 (Gregorian date) through 11/16/2077 23:59:59 (Gregorian date)."

Comment: I'm working with an ERP system that have more than 100 datetimepicker ,one purpose for these datetimepicker is to identify the production and expiry date for the items, it works fine in the English version  but when I changed to Arabic version the min date set to (30-4-1900) and max date set to (13-5-2029), all the people who work with this system have the same problem, so I'm testing some code on another project to figure out how to fix it , I appreciate your help so much. @Andrew Morton

Comment: yes, I'm using Windows 10 @Andrew Morton

Comment: The problem is fixed by adding this line:    '''  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US") '''                  thank you all so much for your help

Comment: Could you change your comment to answer and [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It will help others quickly find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed by adding this line: ''' Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US") '''